# Is it possible to add html to phpinfo page?

Tags: html, php

So I was creating my own phpinfo.php page. It echos out the phpinfo() which is good, but I wanted to add html to it. I wanted to add to the top of the page a back button to take me back to my home directory. Then underneath that link I was gonna display the phpinfo(). I noticed that phpinfo() generates a complete html document with a doctype and everything. Is there a workaround for this? Since if I add my own html tags before I call phpinfo(), the ending result will be an html document underneath some html tags (which obviously isn't w3 standards). I thought about just getting the html output from the phpinfo page and just copying it into the file so I wouldn't be calling phpinfo() but if i ever change something in the future, I'd have to remember to get the new info, copy, paste the html into the document again.

So is there a work around for this?

Comment: You could use an iFrame

Comment: I completly forgot about iFrames (mainly because I never used one in an actual project before lol). Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Or you could use an Ajax.

Comment: @Vince No problem!

Comment: If you want to create your own phpinfo, you can use php functions like: apache_get_modules() (if you use apache), ini_get_all(), php_ini_scanned_files (@see http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-scanned-files.php)...

Answer (score 3):

You may capture the output of phpinfo():

```
// Get phpinfo() HTML
ob_start();
phpinfo();
$phpInfoHtml = ob_get_clean();
```

then use DOM and XPath to extract parts of HTML you want:

```
// Load HTML from string
try {
    $doc = (new DOMDocument())->loadHTML($phpInfoHtml);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n");
}

// XPATH
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
// Scrape your desired node(s)
$body = $xpath->query('//body');
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: In most cases, you should use [Genjo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47902076/5916915). This answer here provides an alternative if you do not have the PHP DOM module (provided by the `php-xml` package in Debian), and for whatever reason, you do not want to install it.

You can add HTML to a phpinfo page like this:

- Get the HTML for the original phpinfo.
- Place the phpinfo's HTML into an iframe.
- Use JavaScript to manipulate the DOM inside the iframe to add/remove HTML.

Example code that adds `<h1>Hello!</h1>` to the top of the page:

```
<?php
ob_start();
phpinfo();
$phpInfoHtml = htmlentities(ob_get_clean());
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>phpinfo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        #iframe {
            /* Make the iframe fill the whole page. */
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        // Add HTML and CSS into the iframe.
        function editFrame() {
            var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument;
            var body = iframe.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

            // Add a header.
            var div = iframe.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML =
                '<div id="header">' +
                    '<h1>Hello!</h1>' +
                '</div>';
            body.insertBefore(div, body.firstChild);

            // Add CSS for the header.
            var css =  // Note: Only one CSS rule allowed per call of insertRule.
                '#header {' +
                    'width: 930px;' +
                    'margin: auto;' +
                '}';
            var sheet = iframe.styleSheets[0];
            sheet.insertRule(css, sheet.cssRules.length);
        }
    </script>

    <!-- The iframe. -->
    <iframe id="iframe" srcdoc="<?php echo $phpInfoHtml ?>" onload="editFrame();" />
</body>
```

Result:

[image: Custom phpinfo]